# How to set Google Drive file icon for files saved by my app?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an app that is integrated into the Google Drive API, and I can create new files in Google Drive.

I have registered icons for my app in the Drive UI Integration page (i.e. both the Application Icon and the Document Icon). The application icon IS being used both in the Open With menu and then New -> [My App] menu on Drive.

However, these icons are not used as the file icon in the listing on drive. I'd like it to show up like it does for other third-party apps:

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Setting a custom MIME in the type in the Drive UI Integration page, and uploading files with that MIME type.
- Manually setting the `iconLink` property in the header, pointing to an online 16x16 .ico file. (Using the v2 API.)

But I still just get the generic "file" icon.

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm trying to do the same thing :(

Comment: Nope. >:( I dropped it for now. Let me know if you do.

Comment: is this fixed? or did you find any workaround? I too face this issue

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive does not take into account the application that created a file when it determines what icon to show. Each file type has a canonical icon that is used for all instances of that file type across all users. Some common file types, like `application/pdf`, have icons created by Google. A file will use an application's icon in two cases:

1. The file is a [shortcut file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create#create_a_shortcut_to_a_file), which by definition means it can only be opened by a single application.
2. An application is algorithmically determined to be the canonical reader/writer for the file type.

The exact algorithm use to determine the canonical application can't be shared, but it's an offline process that requires the application be in use for some time.

Comment: hi Eric, my files _are_ shortcut files. I set the mime type to `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` as specified in the docs, and the shortcut functions as expected (i.e. when I click the shortcut, it hits my app's "open" url that I registered in the developer console), but the icon is still not showing up. I've registered both an application icon and a document icon in the console, at all sizes. what else do I need to do?

Comment: Interesting. I have files created in draw.io in my Drive.They show up with the icon. The files themselves are simply html files -- they end in .html, and when I download them their mimetype is `text/html`. The files themselves, on inspection, are simply a basic html page with a link and a redirect header. How does Google Drive algorithmically determine draw.io to be canonical reader/writer for the file? Why do they show up with an icon?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr didn't work until we publicly published our Chrome web store listing**

I spent a while trying to figure this one out. I tried everything you tried, and more, to no avail. Confusingly, the icon did work for a period of about a week, but then stopped showing up, leaving me even more confused as to whether it was something I had done.

I finally settled on sending our logo as the thumbnail as part of the file data payload, although that's not really a solution because the small icon is still the generic icon, and the thumbnail has its own problems (transparent background shows up as a checkerboard background, scaling and cropping is probably different on different displays).

Finally, after we decided to admit defeat and publicly publish our integration in the Chrome web store, it started working, hopefully this time for good. They really ought to say in the docs that your web store listing needs to be public in order for the logo to show up.